# How can I mount a screen window to an old porch?

Tags: screens

Firstly, this is definitely a related question: [How to install window screen without screen track](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170161/how-to-install-window-screen-without-screen-track)
But the window from in that question is a bit different, and I don't quite see how the answer can be applied to my window.

I recently bought an older home (1920's) with a glass-windowed porch. These windows are not affixed with any sort of track; They are simply on hinges and swing inward.

[image: window top]
[image: window bottom]

They aren't great windows, but whatever, I don't intend to replace them anytime soon. Many bigger fish to fry and whatnot.
However, I do want to get some airflow through the porch, without pets escaping (or letting bugs in).

So far, I was planning to assemble and install a screen frame kit to each window like [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Screen-Tight-5-16-in-x-36-in-White-Aluminum-Window-Screen-Frame-Kit-WSKIT51636/206613125):[image: screen frame kit]
The big question here is, how can I mount this thing to my weird, simplistic, trackless porch frame? I don't care if the screen isn't generally able to be opened (apart from repair/cleaning of course). If I mount it into that inner area just outside of the red window (which seems best? It's a tad over 3/4" deep), I don't have any room for a bottom loop latch. Kinda seems like I need a "hacky" solution, which is probably fine, as long as it doesn't look terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say mount it on the outer part, like @JACK suggested. Otherwise you'll probably end up with some odd-looking custom bracket/track setup to accomplish what you're after.
Instead of the stud screw + wingnut combo though, they make screen clips that match the color and width of that screen kit you linked, which might look a little cleaner. Below is a plastic one (I only searched Home Depot though, so you may find metal ones elsewhere, if that's what you're looking for).

[Screen Clip](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-5-16-in-Plastic-Window-Screen-Clips-8-Pack-L-5773/100559734)
[image: screen clip]

It might be worth investing in stainless steel screws (I didn't see what material the included screws were, but I kinda doubt they're SS), but at $0.30 per clip it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Hmm.. That makes sense. I definitely saw these in my search, but since I was so focused on mounting to the inner part I never really put 2 and 2 together.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mounting them to the inner area why not make the screens an inch or two wider and mount them to the 1x4 vertical members on each side of the windows. They could fit snug up against the top and bottom and be secured on both sides with a few screw studs into the wood lined up with holes in the screen frames. Then fasten the screens to the studs with wing nuts.
Here's a picture of the type of stud to be screwed into the frame... get the stainless steel ones.
[image]

Comment: Wingnuts make sense. It's actually what is holding each of those red windows shut.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen my grandfather make a frame a window screen using 1/2" plywood then nail it to the outside window frame.